# click event on input button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to bind a function to the click event on input button, but it doesn't seems to work and method is not called:

```
<div id='back'>


     <input type="button"/>

     </div>
```

***jQuery:***

```
 $('#back').click(clickOnBackbutton);

              function clickOnBackbutton(){

                console.log('back to menu'); //function not called 

              }
```

I do not prefer to use onClick event, instead i prefer to use that approach. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put your code within document ready handler. also note that you are selecting the div tag instead of the input element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#back input[type=button]').click(clickOnBackbutton);
   // $('#back input[type=button]').click(function(){
   //    or do something here
   // });
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Button:

```
<div id='back'>
    <input type="button" id='back-button'/>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#back-button').click(function(){
       console.log('Back to Menu');
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You bound to the div not the button.

give the button a name or select it as a child then bind the click event.

```
<div id='back'>
    <input id='backbutton' type="button"/>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#backbutton').click(clickOnBackbutton);

function clickOnBackbutton(){
    console.log('back to menu'); //function not called 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function clickOnBackButton(){
  console.log("back to menu");
}

$('#back').click(function(){
  clickOnBackButton();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
$('#back').click(function(){
    clickOnBackButton();
});
```

I don't think there's such a thing as an input type="button". Maybe type="submit" ?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use:

```
$('#back').on('click', function(){
  // some action
});
```

Comment: There is no difference between `click` on `on('click')`

Comment: @undefined With this use, you're right. But using `on` with 3 parameters is different :)

Answer (score 1):

JQuery 1.7+ you should attach the event using on.

```
function clickOnBackbutton(){
    console.log('back to menu'); //function not called 
}
$(document).on("click", "#back", clickOnBackbutton);
```

[Running example](http://jsfiddle.net/3Wbm7/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want `div#back` to capture clicked button event, then with the recent jquery you have to do this:

```
$('#back').on("click", "input[type=button]", clickOnBackbutton);
```

Note that you have to put script tag in the end of body, or wrap your code in `$(document).ready` event.

Comment: I am puting all that jQuery code in a separate file which i include in my main file, shall i put it always in `$(document).ready` event ?

Comment: You don't have to use `$(document).ready` if your `script` tag is in the end of body, just before `</body>` closing tag. If you choose to put `script` tags in `head` then you have to wrap your code in document ready event, because your script is executed before  page is rendered.